# Playing and recording a live stream from another computer webcam using VLC/FFmpeg

Tags: ubuntu, video, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, video-streaming

I was trying lately to set a video server on one machine and play it in a differen machine, it works with me.. but the problem is that it always stuck and become jammed in the middle .. and it is very slow comparing to the original stream.. something like 5 seconds delay which is not acceptable at all!

The warning messages I get usually includes something like that:

In the client side, which is the one which is jammed.

```
[0x24d1ab0] ts demux warning: discontinuity received 0x5 instead of 0xe (pid=68)
[0x7f4340015e50] rtp demux warning: 2 packet(s) lost
reference picture missing during reorder
Missing reference picture
mmco: unref short failure
Reference 4 >= 4 (H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10)) stopped
error while decoding MB 34 14, bytestream (575)
```

And that is the picture of the streaming when it is jammed:

[image: jammed stream]

And that is what it looks like when it is running smoothly:

[image: smooth stream]

This is the error message I got on the server:

```
[0x2513820] main generic debug: auto hidding mouse
[0x2296230] main mux warning: late buffer for mux input (1840085)
```

And finally here is my command line that I am using on the server:

```
vlc -vvv v4l2:///dev/video1:v4l2-width=640:v4l2-height=480 --sout
'#duplicate{dst=display,dst="transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=800,ab=128}
:duplicate{dst=rtp{mux=ts,dst=172.22.2.87,port=50004}'
```

On the client:

```
vlc -vvv rtp://@:50004
```

I thought that it might be from VLC or from my command .. I tried different protocols for transmission, with no luck. I also tried FFmpeg and I got similar results + warning messages. I thought then that both of them are using the same libraries in Linux.

Here is the command using FFmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video1 -vcodec libx264 -s 320x240 -pix_fmt
yuv420p -vb 200000 -minrate 200000 -maxrate 200000 -bufsize 2000000 -acodec
libmp3lame -ab 128k -ar 44100 -ac 2 -f mpegts udp://172.22.2.87:5544
```

In conclusion, I would like to find a solution for the latency of the streaming (which is very high) and the jamming problem.